# Why internal hyperlinkes like social media in wordpress website open other linkes?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

```
<?php if (ot_get_option('fb_link')) { ?>
<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo ot_get_option('fb_link'); ?>" 
class="boxed-icon facebook icon-1x"><i class="icon-budicon-834"></i></a>
<?php } ?>
```

> At this website http://www.tanmiaegypt.com/en when open on
>   chrome and click on any hyperlinks like social media links didn't go
>   to the true link but open other pages on the same website.

Comment: can you add a link? or more details

Comment: If you turn off Javascript, they work. So something in your Javascript is preventing them from working.

Comment: @Mor Haviv you can find what i mean when open website and click on any social media links for example facebook.  website is http://www.tanmiaegypt.com/en

Answer (score 0):

> To resolve this issue check plugins because some plugins scripts
>   conflict with the mail wordpress scripts so after updated my plugins
>   this issue resolved.